# How to use a dynamically created string that matches a local variable as that variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array set:

```
metrics = ['value_one', 'value_two', 'value_three', 'value_four', 'value_five']
```

I then iterate the gathered scores and sum the values of each metric:

```
survey_scores.each do |ss|
  if ss.survey.has_questions_for_metric?('value_one')
    value_one_count += 1
    value_one_score += ss.value_one_score
  end
  if ss.survey.has_questions_for_metric?('value_two')
    value_two_count += 1
    value_two_score += ss.value_two_score
  end
  if ss.survey.has_questions_for_metric?('value_three')
    value_three_count += 1
    value_three_score += ss.value_three_score
  end
  if ss.survey.has_questions_for_metric?('value_four')
    value_four_count += 1
    value_four_score += ss.value_four_score
  end
  if ss.survey.has_questions_for_metric?('value_five')
    value_five_count += 1
    value_five_score += ss.value_five_score
  end
end
```

I want to retrieve those values so I can add the weights to them and I want to do this dynamically instead of writing five `if`/`else` statements that are doing the same thing. I'm using:

```
metrics.each do |metric|
  if survey.has_questions_for_metric?(metric)
    puts "#{metric}_adjusted_score"
    "#{metric}_adjusted_score" = "#{metric}_score" / "#{metric}_count"
  end
end
```

but this throws a syntax error

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
```

pointing to the equals sign.  I assume it is reading these as strings that mean nothing, but I'm not sure.  If I output to a log it shows the correct variable text `value_one_adjusted_score` etc.,  but I need it to be equal to the value of that variable which is set when I go through all the scores.

I haven't found a solution that would allow me to access variables in a dynamic way.

Comment: What is `"#{metric}_score"`? What is `"#{metric}_count"`? Where those come from?

Comment: They are integer values created when I loop through the scores

Comment: They are strings in the first place.

Comment: updated my code with how those values are tallied

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We can't run the code.

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry, I guess I didn't think running the code was required.  I was only asking how to set a variable dynamically.  Not sure how you could run the code, or why you would even need to, without having the data which I have no real way to provide here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not do this. Assemble a hash instead with

```rb
scores =
  metrics.each_with_object({}) do |metric, acc|
    if survey.has_questions_for_metric?(metric)
      acc["#{metric}_adjusted_score"] = ...
    end
  end
```

Local variables have a lot of limitations, including but not limited to scoping issues; with local variables, you’d need to tackle with `binding` and the code soo would become a nightmare to support, even despite it’s somewhat possible.

---

The block updating scores might be simplified to:

```rb
survey_scores.
      each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {} }) do |ss|
  %w[value_one value_two value_three].each do |metric, acc|
    next unless ss.survey.has_questions_for_metric?(metric)

    acc[metric]["#{metric}_count"] += 1
    acc[metric]["#{metric}_score"] +=
      ss.public_send("#{metric}_score")
  end
end
```

Comment: Good answer. You actually can't define new local variables dynamically even if you use eval or binding.local_variable_set since both run in a separate context and the local variable will just be set there. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set